# Can I schedule backups using the Heroku PG Backup add-on?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backup, add-on

I have been using [PG Backups add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) recently and everything has worked fine, however this morning the backup process triggered at 10:00 A.M. in the morning generating some blocks and timeouts in my application.

Is there a way to specify the schedule of the backups made with this add-on? I've been searching and haven't found anything specific.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Cron for Manual Backup Scheduling

Heroku gives you two types of backups: automated and user-initiated. Each plan has a different number of daily, weekly, and manual backups that are retained. You can't control when the automated backups occur with [PG Backups Auto](https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups), but you can use cron to trigger a "manual" backup at any time.

For example:

```
# Trigger a "manual" backup every four hours.
0 */4 * * * source $HOME/database_credentials; heroku pgbackups:capture
```

See [Creating a Backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#creating-a-backup)  for more information about using the pgbackups command.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do it currently, aside from using an external process to fire the calls.

An email to support might reveal more.

Answer (score 0):

While the original question is old, Heroku does have a schedule option for PGBackups now:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups