# Heroku: Can I schedule PostgreSQL backups using the Scheduler add-on (maybe with pgbackups)?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, cron, backup

I have a small app, and I run backups manually using `heroku pgbackups:capture` on my dev machine.
I'd like to use the Heroku Scheduler send these backups to my own S3 bucket.
The thing is: `pg_dump` is not an available on Heroku boxes, and `heroku pgbackups:capture` is a local CLI command, also not available.
Is there another way to achieve this using Scheduler?

Comment: What didn't you like about the various answers you get when searching for "heroku cron" on here and google?

Comment: @RichardHuxton None of the answers seem to address my case, can I run ```heroku pgbackups:capture``` or any other heroku command on heroku cron? A downvote for that, really?

Comment: For still not explaining what is wrong with e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959441/can-i-schedule-backups-using-the-heroku-pg-backup-add-on yes, a downvote doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: The question you linked to suggests using ```heroku pgbackups:capture```, but this is a local CLI command and won't work on Heroku Scheduler

Comment: See - with a little bit of editing your question now clearly expresses what you want to achieve. I don't understand *why* you can't just run the pgbackup on the target node, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: And the question you linked earlier (which I hadn't seen before your comment) headed me in the right direction: I contacted Heroku support and was informed it can't be done!